# Ping Port Number

Tags: ping, icmp

I'm just wondering, is there a port number used for the ping command. I have dissected the ping packet on Wireshark, but I haven't seen any destination or source ports. Am I just missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Port numbers are layer-4 addresses for *some* layer-4 protocols, e.g. TCP or UDP. Other layer-4 protocols may use something else, or nothing at all.

ICMP does not use port numbers. ICMP acts like a layer-4 protocol, but it is really an integral part of IP, a layer-3 protocol that knows nothing about port numbers. See [*RFC 792, INTERNET CONTROL MESSAGE PROTOCOL*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc792):

> ICMP, uses the basic support of IP as if it were a higher level
> protocol, however, ICMP is actually an integral part of IP, and must
> be implemented by every IP module.

Ping, itself, is an application that uses ICMP echo requests and replies.